# Agora.io - How to remove echo sound when using video chat

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, videochat

I'm trying to implement the code sample for basic video call
Everything run smoothly, it just that when I talk to phone A, the sound transfer to phone B with additional echo in the end of sentence, anyone know how to remove the echo sound.
It happened with my A10 and A71 and on computer also.
my scripts:

```
public void JoinChannel(string channelName)
{
    //set callback
    Debug.Log("Join channel");
    screen1.SetActive(true);
    screen2.SetActive(true);
    joinButton.SetActive(false);
    inputField.SetActive(false);
    mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = OnJoinChannelSuccess;
    mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined = OnUserJoined;
    mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline = OnUserOffline;
    
    //enable video
    mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();

    //allow camera output callback
    mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();

    //join the channel
    mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(channelName, null, 0);
}
private void OnUserJoined(uint uid, int elapsed)
{
    textDebug.GetComponent<Text>().text = "OnUserJoined";
    Debug.Log("OnUserJoined");
    GameObject go;
    go = screen1;
    go.name = uid.ToString();

    VideoSurface o = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
    o.SetForUser(uid);
    o.SetEnable(true);
    Debug.Log(uid);

    mRemotePeer = uid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Agora SDK supports echo cancellation. In most cases, this problem can be fixed by using a headset, and ensure that the headset does not cause an echo.

In a channel joined by multiple users, if a device does not work properly, chances are that all other users in the channel can hear echoes. Therefore, beware that the user hearing the echo may not necessarily be the one having the problem.

Self-check Steps:
Check the following:

Find the source of the echo. You can mute users in the channel one by one to find the source of the echo.
Check if the echo is occasional or continuous. An occasional echo may be caused by CPU overload. By using Call Search function of Agora Analytics, you can check the CPU usage on the End-to-End Details page.
Ensure that all users are in separated physical environments and do not sit too close to each other.
Check the SDK version:

- Android/iOS: v1.6.0+.
- Windows/macOS: v1.7.0+.

Check if you enabled an external audio source. If so, echo cancellation is turned off by default.
In Windows, ensure the Monitoring Microphone option is not checked.
On iOS, check whether the app sets Audio Session as AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers. If so, you may encounter echoes when other apps use the audio device at the same time.
Systems of some Android or Windows devices support echo cancellation function by default, and you may encounter echoes if the echo cancellation of the system is poor. In this case, Agora recommends disabling the echo cancellation in system and using the echo cancellation of Agora.

Use a headset:
In a one-to-one call, if you hear an echo, ask the other user to use a headset.
In a multi-user call, ask users to mute in turn to figure out who causes the echo. The users who cause the echo should use headsets or mute themselves.

For further assistance and up to date FAQ, see  https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/echo

Comment: seem that if two device in one room, there will be echo, will test more to see